# What is the best practice to make microservice aware about name of another microservice for interaction

Tags: java, kubernetes, deployment, microservices

I have couple of microservices written in spring boot which interact with each other to perform certain task. I need to deploy these microservices in AWS using Kubernetes. In order for microservices to interact with each other, one service need to know the name of other service. This is where I am not sure how to proceed.

Since I am planning to deploy using Kubernetes, I will create Kubernetes services for both microservices and also want to leverage DNS resolving of Kubernetes. Now my question is how do I make one microservice aware of Kubernetes service names. One option I can think of is, put the name of microservice in application.properties and create the Kubernetes service with same name but with this approach I have the impression that I am planning for failure. If somehow name of my service needs to be changed in future, then I also need to remember to change the name in each microservice which depends on this.

I assume this is very common scenario which people might be facing during microservices deployment using Kubernetes. So, What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the service names as environment variables.  It's okay to directly embed these in the clients' YAML specifications (this is slightly easier if you're using a templating tool like Helm), though using an indirect ConfigMap works too.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: other-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80          # make the Service use the standard HTTP port
      targetPort: http  # even if the Pod uses something else
...
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  ...
    env:
      - name: OTHERSERVICE_URL
        value: http://other-service
```

Every language has some way to retrieve environment variables (Python `os.environ[]`, Node `process.env`, ...) so you can use this approach regardless of the implementation language.  If the environment variable isn't set, make its default value be something that will be useful to a developer, perhaps a `localhost` URL on a known port.

In a Spring Boot client specifically, [environment variables can be directly used as Spring properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.3/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) (see also [more specific rules for environment variable names](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.3/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding-from-environment-variables)) so your `application.yml` file can specify

```yaml
other-service:
  url: http://localhost:12345
```

and then your client can be configured with

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="other-service")
@Data
public class OtherServiceClient {
  private String url;
}
```

Do not try to use Spring property files to configure service URLs here.  (In a Helm context you could dynamically construct a complete property file in a ConfigMap, but the environment-variable approach is more generic.)  Since the URL could have pretty much any host name (again, especially in a Helm context, where the names are usually constructed) you don't want to have to recompile your jar file to redeploy to somewhere new.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is using Config map and add those mirco services URL in config map. Then you can mount them in deployment pod template and use them in your application.

So in future, if you need to change micro service URL, you have to change the config map accordingly nothing else.

If you want micro service address as env, then you config map will be like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service-config
data:
  micro_service_1: "value1"
  micro_service_2: "value2"
```

Or you can use them in some properties file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service-config
data:
  service.properties: |
    micro_service_1: "value1"
    micro_service_2: "value2"
```

Then mount them in your deployment pod template spec:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: demo
      image: alpine
      env:
        - name: MICROSERVICE_1
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: service-config
              key: microservice_1
        - name: MICROSERVICE_2
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: service-config
              key: microservice_2
      # you will need volumeMounts and volumes if and only if you use service address from properties file. Then you can skip above env part
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config
        mountPath: "/config"
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    # You set volumes at the Pod level, then mount them into containers inside that Pod
    - name: config
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap you want to mount.
        name: secret-config
        # An array of keys from the ConfigMap to create as files
        items:
        - key: "service.properties"
          path: "service.properties"
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you need to necessarily create a volume to use config map. Is it?

Comment: Yes, but if you want the config in a file into a specific path instead of env, then you will need a volume.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that much familier with the kubernates and how much you can leverage the DNS resolving of Kubernetes. But if you are using spring boot you can leverage Spring cloud, which provides some of the solutions/services called as **Service discovery/registry** which can be used to lookup various microservices and you can use feign clients for communication between them.

You need to create Eureka(netflix Eureka is pet-project under Spring cloud) server where your client services will register themselves(in your case different different microservices) and your microservies will be clients to this server.

you can find spring.io documentation which will provide you basic example to set this up.

here https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

and about feign which are declarative REST clients here
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html